# jQuery UI closethick icon not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

Right now, the close button in my dialog looks like this:

[image: closethick icon]

It's supposed to look more like an X, and did up until recently. I don't know how the jQuery UI dialog buttons are constructed (I assumed they were simple images, but it looks like that's not the case), so I don't know how I could have broken it, but I assume it's some CSS interference.

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Probably some CSS rule that redefine the width/height of spans. Inspect the element and note down the rules that apply to it; then check the rules that were added by _your_ CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, looks like it was a stray `background-position` property marked as `!important`.